# Can zksnark prove DLP?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, discrete-logarithm, snarks

Can one use zksnark to prove the knowledge of a discrete logarithm? In another word, can zksnark (R1CS) encode exponentiation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

final_exp_gadget<>() of libsnark could be a practical example to tune for DLP.
The idea is, "final exponentiation" is a part of Ate pairing, that is verified as a part of check_e_equals_e_gadget<>(), which stands for Groth16 verification equation.

Comment: Just curious, if R1CS is eventually translated into arithmetic gate circuit, how would the expnentiation like x^y is encoded as a circuit? Would we end up with a loop of multiplication gates, since "y" is a variable here.

Comment: Start from splitting exponent "y" into bits, then square-and-conditional-multiply loop.  @Sean

Comment: That's right! Thanks again!

Comment: I'm looking at zokrate (instead of direclty cut into the libsnark as you suggested) - it looks like its language spec does not support  power operations also the loop is bounded. Are there any particular reason for this? -- in another word, could this make proof generation too costly in zksnark? (looks like not to me - as square-and-multiply would be linear with the number of bits - the number of gates needed cound't be a very large number)

Comment: Zokrates is still in my todo pipline, sorry. Gate cost/complexity should be the same as with libsnark, as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for sure! R1CS is an NP-complete language. It is basically a characterization of arithmetic circuits, hence every computation can be expressed as a R1CS.

[There are](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2641562) compilers that reduce program executions to R1CS. One of my favourite tools is [Zokrates](https://zokrates.github.io/).